# Removing GUID from linked datasource

Tags: 2007, deployment, data-view-web-part

I'm deploying a DVWP and I'm looking to remove GUIDs references from the datasource.

This is fine for standard single satasources, but I'm having troubles with joined datasources.

Here's (a portion of) what SPD gave me to start with.

```
            <DataSources>
                <SharePointWebControls:aggregatedatasource runat="server" IsSynchronous="false" SeparateRoot="true" id="aggregatedatasource2">
                    <sources>
                        <SharePointWebControls:spdatasource runat="server" DataSourceMode="List" UseInternalName="true" selectcommand="&lt;View&gt;&lt;/View&gt;">
                            <SelectParameters>
                                <asp:Parameter Name="ListID" DefaultValue="{CF046268-D9EB-4428-B621-97D2D4B3021B}"/>
                            </SelectParameters>
```

I've replaced Name and the GUId to ListName and myListName, the part errors in the browser.

I've seen [Marc's post](http://sympmarc.com/2009/12/10/a-jquery-library-for-sharepoint-web-services-wss-3-0-and-moss-real-world-example-part-2/) but my tags are different. I've tried replacing values from the datasource in the post with my list values but no luck.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Dan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a sample for a session I give on Content Aggregation. You don't need the WebURL parameter if the list exists in the current site.

```
<SharePoint:SPDataSource runat="server"
   DataSourceMode="List"
   UseInternalName="True"
   UseServerDataFormat="True"
   selectcommand="<View></View>">
   <SelectParameters>
      <asp:Parameter Name="ListName" DefaultValue="Announcements"/>
      <asp:Parameter Name="WebURL" DefaultValue="/demos/contentquery/red/"/>
   </SelectParameters>
</SharePoint:SPDataSource>
```

Comment: That was it. Once I added in the WebURL it all came good.

Answer (score 0):

Try to export website as template and import wsp to Visual Studio. SharePoint will replace ListIDs with urls.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how the AggregateDataSource is constructed, you may need to replace the word ListID with ListName twice in each parameter.

Also, as Chris alludes, you need the WebURL for any list which is not in the current site.

This trick absolutely works in AggregateDataSources; I do it all the time. Keep at it!